# Dark spots on dieffenbachia leaves

Tags: diagnosis, indoors

I have this plant for some months, but it didn't turn out healthy... About 2 months ago these dark spots began to appear and the leaves wither shortly after. I remove the leaves as soon as the spots appear, but they keep coming up.

[image]

I water it about once a week but the dirt seems too wet. I've also used liquid fertilizer a couple of times. Will it be ok?

Here is the whole plant.
[image]

The pot has drainage holes. I used dark soil with compost (this was written in its description) and perlite. You can see it here too:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a photo of the whole plant, as well as adding info regarding what soil you used in the pot, whether the pot has drainage holes, and how long has the plant had this problem please?

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Coolkoon's comment, but the soil does not have enough time to dry-out. The culprit may be some old or inadequate potting soil which holds too much water, hence appearing as an overwatering problem. You may check one of the following:

1- Type of soil: May need longer to dry-out, may be used-up soil which crumbled and became more water-retentive, reducing aeration as well. You may take some new soil and compare it with that one. If you find the two are different, it may be time to replace that potting soil!

2- Clogged or missing drainage holes. Whether it is true or not, you may find it out when you replace your potting soil.

Answer (score 1):

If your plant is still alive, I think that the key sentence you said is "I water it about once a week but the dirt seems too wet." I think that the browning is due to overwatering. You need to water the plant only and only if the soil is dry, not at a fix period (say, one week). The plant's water intake entirely depends on the amount of nutrients it has, the light it gets and the ambient temperature. Since you might keep the plant on a fairly dark spot in your room (although I'd avoid full sun as well, the leaves might not like that either) the general rule of thumb is to water it only when the soil is dry and not more often than that (even if that means watering only every 1.5 or 2 weeks).